# Как сверстать прямоугольный блок с кружочками?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Есть [макет в Figma](https://www.figma.com/file/rQEA5DpFYwAIeGhYXHKSPl/school?node-id=1%3A3366).

В макете есть несколько прямоугольных блоков с кружочками.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В разных местах макета кружочки имеют разные размеры. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как сверстать такие блоки: просто вырезать их как изображения или сделать в виде div-блока для каждого кружка с нужными размерами? Как будет правильно с точки зрения хороших практик верстки?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

div {
  margin: auto;
  width: calc(16px * 11);
  height: calc(16px * 6);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px pink;
  border: 16px solid white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, pink 4px, transparent 4px);
  background-size: 16px 16px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Премного благодарю. Очень элегантное решение!